# Extremal value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

My lecturer explained the concept of EVT quite poorly and so I am left quite confused - could someone clear up what exactly it is and how it can be used in the real analysis course I’m taking? So far we’ve covered stuff such as epsilon delta and epsilon n proofs for convergence of sequence, series & stuff like function continuity etc.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you have a continuous, real valued function $f$ on a compact set (say a closed interval $[a,b]$, and $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$), then there exists points $x_m,x_M \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_M) \geq f(x)$ and $f(x_m) \leq f(x)$ for all $x$. That is to say, the function has points where it achieves its max and min.

Comment: Hi, one irrelevant thing: this is not a "functional-analysis" question. Consider the tag removed. Please try your best to choose appropriate tags. Maybe wiki would tell you what the tags mean.

Comment: @user10793176, why don't you check the wiki site for EVT(https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) , everything is explained there quite properly . Especially, read the different proofs , they will clear the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: This is long. You may need more than an hour to understand all these. Try to draw pictures/read again the theorems used if you get stuck.

Understanding the Extreme Value Theorem is not an easy task. You can get some intuitions from counter-examples (that do not satisfy the conditions), but to actually prove it is hard.

Now I want to give some examples of functions that do not achieve its minimum/maximum.

1. Consider $f(x)=x^2$ on $(0,1)$. Clearly $f$ is continuous on $(0,1)$, and $0<f(x)<1 \,\forall x \in (0,1).$ However, $f$ does not achieve its maximum and minimum on $(0,1)$. While you may want to say that $\sup_{x \in (0,1)} f(x)=1$ and $\inf_{x \in (0,1)} f(x)=0$, $\nexists\, x \in (0,1)$ s.t. $x^2=0$ or $x^2=1$.
2. Consider $f(x)=e^x$ on $[0,\infty)$. Then $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ which is a closed interval. However, $[0,\infty)$ is not bounded, and clearly $f$ does not achieve its maximum on $[0,\infty).$
3. Consider $f(x)=|x| \,\forall x \in [-1,0) \cup(0,1]$ and $f(0)=\frac{1}{2}$. Then $f$ is bounded on $[-1,1]$, but $f$ is not continuous at $0$, and it does not achieve its minimum on $[-1,1]$. (Clearly $\inf_{x \in [-1,1]}f(x)=0$.)

After all these, you should (?) be able to get some feelings when a function $f$ achieves its maximum/minimum on the boundary of the domain (say, a closed interval), and continuity is important because $f$ will not blow up in the middle of the interval.

Now to actually prove the theorem, you first show that $f$ being continuous on a closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$ is bounded. Hence the supremum and infimum exists. Then show that they are achievable.

Step 1: Suppose $f$ is not bounded above. Then by definition, $\exists \{x_n\} \subset [a,b]$ s.t. $f(x_n)>n \,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now apply Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem to get a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\} \subset [a,b]$ that converges to some $x_0$, as $n_k \to \infty$. Since $[a,b]$ is closed, we must have $x_0 \in [a,b].$ This is trivial if you know some elementary topology, but you can also show this easily by $\epsilon-\delta$ arguments. On one hand, since $\{x_{n_k}\}$ is a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$, $\{f(x_{n_k})\}$ must be unbounded. On the other hand, since $f$ is continuous, we apply sequential criterion to conclude that $f(x_{n_k}) \to f(x_0)$, as $n_k \to \infty$. Since the tail of a convergent sequence must be bounded, can you get a contradiction here? Now, apply the same argument to conclude that $f$ is bounded below on $[a,b]$.

Step 2: By axiom of completeness (or equivalence) $M=\sup_{x \in [a,b]} f(x)$ and $m=\inf_{x \in [a,b]} f(x)$ exist. Now we want to show that they are achievable. By definition, $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \, x_{\epsilon} \in [a,b]$ s.t. $M \ge f(x_{\epsilon})>M-\epsilon$. Hence $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists \, x_n \in [a,b]$ s.t. $M \ge f(x_n)>M-\frac{1}{n}$. If we can show that $x_n \to x_M$ as $n \to \infty$, then we have $f(x_n) \to f(x_M)$ as $n \to \infty$. Apply Squeeze Theorem, we indeed have $f(x_M)=M$. In general we do not know whether $\{x_n\}$ converges, but because $\{x_n\} \subset [a,b]$, we can apply Bolzano-Weierstrass again, getting a convergent subsequence and conclude that such $x_M \in [a,b]$ is indeed the maximizer,  being equal to the limit of the convergent subsequence. Apply the same argument to show that there is a minimizer $x_m \in [a,b]$.

Again, this is long, and you may need more than an hour to digest all these. After all, this is one of the proofs that uses most of the more elementary theorems. Therefore, first understand supremum and infimum properties, Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, sequential criterion and continuity, and properties of sequences in close and bounded intervals. After that, try to follow the proof line-by-line to follow the logic.